# How can I toggle mobile data from a terminal?

Tags: terminal, mobile-data

I have a rooted Sony Xperia 3 running CyanogenMod 10. Can I turn off mobile data from the terminal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the terminal, you can use `svc` to control several elements of your device. For mobile data, it would be:

- To disable: `svc data disable`
- To enable: `svc data enable`

You can simply type `svc help` for a list of available commands, or `svc help [command]` for a list of subcommands. For example:

- To get the list of subcommands for controlling mobile data: `svc help data`
- To get the list of subcommands for controlling wifi: `svc help wifi`

Comment: `svc data disable` didn't work without root permission. Any suggestion for an un-rooted device?

Comment: I don't believe it's possible for an unrooted device.